# Android Gestures code explanation

Tags: java, android, gesture, gesturedetector

I am a beginner in android, and I was going through thenewboston tutorials. I came across this code for gesture recognition.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myMessage);
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

}
```

I looked up the documentation for `GestureDetectorCompat`, and could see that the constructor used was `GestureDetectorCompat(Context context, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener)`

However, I couldn't understand how `new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);` will create this object. What is the `(this, this)` referring to? Where is it getting from? Is there another way to create this object that could help me understand this?

Comment: My friends created an app about your problem, maybe the code helps you
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2351974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter `this` is the context of your current activity. (SO question about the idea of context [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)) The second one is again `this`, because your activity should implement `implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener` and that's why you could write instead of

```
... new GestureDetector(this, new OnGestureListener() {...} ); 
//and then
gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {...});
```

just

```
... new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
//and
gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
```

If you do not want to use the construction you posted (with `this` parameters), than you could easily use the full construction like this for example (just an example of the full use):

```
gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {

     @Override 
     public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
         return false; 
     } 

     @Override 
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
         mapView.getController().zoomInFixing((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
         return false; 
     }
     //you could override more methods here if you want 
}
```